# Asp.net mvc webgrid search

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an Asp.net MVC 4 application. I have added a web grid to this application. Some how a search box is shown on top of this grid.

[image]

My first preference is to remove this,
if I cant remove it, I want to control the behavior i.e. what column to filter.

Here is the code

```
@model IEnumerable<Fai.Backend.Services.Models.CaseListModel>
<script type="text/javascript">   


</script>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}
<h2>Index</h2>

<div class="row">
    <div class="columns twelve">
    <select id="statusFilter">
        <option value='0'>@Fai.Backend.Services.Utilities.TextProvider.StatusOpen </option>
        <option value='1'>@Fai.Backend.Services.Utilities.TextProvider.StatusClosed </option>
        <option value='2' selected="selected">@Fai.Backend.Services.Utilities.TextProvider.StatusAll</option>
    </select>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="dataTable">
    @{
        var grid = new WebGrid(source:Model,canPage:false);
    @grid.GetHtml(

            columns: grid.Columns(grid.Column("Date", @Fai.Backend.Services.Utilities.TextProvider.Text.CreatedOn, canSort: true ),
            grid.Column("Title", @Fai.Backend.Services.Utilities.TextProvider.Text.Title, canSort: true),
            grid.Column("NameOfCreatingUser", @Fai.Backend.Services.Utilities.TextProvider.Text.CreatedBy, canSort: true),
            grid.Column("Company", @Fai.Backend.Services.Utilities.TextProvider.Text.Company, canSort: true),
            grid.Column("Organization", @Fai.Backend.Services.Utilities.TextProvider.Text.Organization, canSort: true),
            grid.Column("Status", @Fai.Backend.Services.Utilities.TextProvider.Text.Status, canSort: true),
            grid.Column("", format: @<text>@Html.ActionLink(Fai.Backend.Services.Utilities.TextProvider.Text.ViewCaseDetails, "Details", "Case", new { id = item.Id }, null)</text>)
                      ));
    }
</div>
```

Comment: Could you show the code where you have *added* this grid? Also in your question you seem to be talking about ASP.NET MVC 4 and yet your question is tagged with asp.net-mvc-3. So which one is it?

Comment: I have updated the post with code,

Comment: Is this the only related view?  There is no search box here.  If it's added by javascript, where's the javascript?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest (but not recommended way) is to simply hide it in CSS.  Just right click it in chrome or firefox and you'll see which style you need to add "display: none" to.  Otherwise, post your code, as suggested by Darin in the comments.

Comment: this would be my last resort. for now just want to see if I can solve it properly.

Answer (score 0):

It was my mistake there was a JavaScript in the _Layout.cshtml was creating this filter box. Here the javascript for reference

```
$('.dataTable > table').dataTable(
                  {
                      "bPaginate": false,
                      "bLengthChange": false,
                      "bFilter": true,
                      "bSort": false,
                      "bInfo": false,
                      "bAutoWidth": true
                  }
                  );
```